# Pattern to match with starting letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

Im using `tableutils.js` plug in, inside this, its regular expression for filtering is :

```
 var pattern = new RegExp(filter.expr,'i');
```

its filtering if I type letter `T`,
its shows item containing

`Tony`

`Captain`

its working pattern is like in `MYSQL` `LIKE %%`,In regex im using this `/^'+filter.expr+'/i` but its not working.Can anyone check my pattern,if i missed out something.Thanks in advance.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/md91vd5k/)

Comment: Type `^t` to match only the first letter.

Comment: I'm probably going blind, but looking at the posted fiddle, where is this regular expression you're talking about ?

Comment: @adeneo It's in the third-party plugin he's using.

Comment: @Barmar - That's what I thought, but how are we supposed to change that ?

Comment: @adeneo,the regex code is on the plug in i used,https://raw.githack.com/kolgepratik/tableutils/master/js/tableutils.js heres the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the plugin to only match the first letter, change that line to:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^' + filter.expr, 'i');
```

You can't use variables inside regexp literals in `/.../`. You have to work with them as strings, then use `new RegExp` to convert the string to a RegExp.

Comment: You would think you could actually set this from the options passed when initializing the plugin, and there is a filter setting, but the plugin has absolutely no documentation or comments.

Comment: Use the source, Luke. It looks like there are two special filter types: checkbox and numeric. Anything else is just a regexp to be matched, with no options to modify it like my answer.

Comment: @adeneo,im only having troble with the regex,but anything works fine, Barmar answer works for me.

Comment: @Barmar,also sir can you check why this is not working for `$('#filter_searchMe_2').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );` to filter third column?

Comment: Do you have three elements in your `filter: { type: [...] }` option?